How to skip edges shared between two triangles when conservative rasterization
When enabling conservative rasterization, there are lots of fragments generated from edges.
How to skip fragments generated from edges shared between two triangles?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

My Solution: Run two raster passes. The first is ConversativeRasterizationEnabled==false, and the second is ConversativeRasterizationEnabled==true. Using depth test to discard or overwrite fragments generated from shared edges.
